# RxJs. How to throw error and continue emiting values if I have a two observable?

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, try-catch, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-catcherror-withmapoperators-lwutxg?file=index.ts

```
const fakeRequest$ = of().pipe(
  tap((_) => console.log('fakeRequest')),
  throwError
);

const iWillContinueListening$ = fromEvent(
  document.getElementById('continued'),
  'click'
).pipe(
  switchMap((_) =>
    fakeRequest$.pipe(
      catchError((_) => {
        return throwError('x');
      })
    )
  )
);

const parent = iWillContinueListening$.pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log('er', err);
    return of('err');
  })
);



parent.subscribe(console.log);
```

How to activate catchError on parrent on error in iWillContinueListening$  and still emit values ?

Comment: Maybe `retry` or `retryWhen` is what you need? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retry https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen

Comment: It's very hard for me to tell what are you trying to do. When a chain emits an `error` notification it will terminate and there will never be any more `next` emissions. Maybe you're looking for `retry()` or maybe even `onErrorResumeNext()`?

Answer (score 0):

For looking the effect you're trying to achieve, your `iWillContinueListening$` observable should never throw an error. It should catch the error and return a fallback value instead.

```
const iWillContinueListening$ = fromEvent(
  document.getElementById('continued'),
  'click'
).pipe(
  switchMap((_) =>
    fakeRequest$.pipe(
      catchError((_) => {
        //return throwError('x'); <--commenting this
        return of('x');  <-- adding this
      })
    )
  )
);
```